# Create Docker container with Python SDK and execute commands in it

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

I'm trying to create one Docker container using Docker Python SDK, and keep executing some commands in it and get some results.

I found in docs that I can run the container execute a command and then this container is gone

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
client.containers.run('alpine', 'echo hello world')
```

or create a container and make it run as daemon

```
container = client.containers.run('bfirsh/reticulate-splines',
                                  detach=True)
```

but still I don't know how to keep the container running and send it commands to execute, Is this possible? or Am I missing something? or Am I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what you want to achieve. But if that helps, here is how I create a docker container from an image:

```
import docker as docker_sdk


docker = docker_sdk.from_env()

docker.containers.run(image='name_of_your_image',                                                                                                                                                      
                      command='/usr/sbin/your_command --arg 123 --abc',                                                                                                                              
                      name=CONTAINER_NAME,                                                                                                                                              
                      hostname='host',                                                                                                                                                   
                      volumes={                                                                                                                                                         
                          '/container_directory': {                                                                                                                                       
                              'bind': '/host/home/user/directory',                                                                                                                             
                              'mode': 'rw'                                                                                                                                              
                          }                                                                                                                                                             
                      },                                                                                                                                                                
                      detach=True)
```

Docs and examples are available here: https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html